# Dbt - The selection criterion [model name] does not match any node

Tags: dbt

When running command `dbt run -s [model_name]`  I get the error: `The selection criterion [model name] does not match any node`.

Any suggestions why this problem occurs?

- The model name was copied 1-on-1 and is exactly the same as in the dbt directory
- The command works for other models

Comment: This is tough to answer without (a) the actual command you're running and (b) the full path to the `.sql` file

Comment: This was indeed the solution , thank you @JoshD.

Answer (score -2):

This was solved (in my case) by adding `.sql` to the filename. Dbt only finds model names with `.sql`. For instance: `ODL_base__model` is *not* found, whereas `ODL_base__model.sql` is found

Comment: @MOT I think Josh D. adjusted his anwer, but find my solution above.